setup buffer I/O in C for ARM OS
I want ot make tiny OS. With buffer, because when i tryed to realise commands i have troubles with buffer. Here full C code:
#include <stdint.h>

#define UART0_BASE 0x09000000
#define UART0_DR (UART0_BASE + 0x00)
#define UART0_FR (UART0_BASE + 0x18)

typedef unsigned long size_t; // Define size_t for compatibility

void uart_putc(char c){
    volatile uint32_t *UARTFR = (uint32_t *)UART0_FR;
    volatile uint32_t *UARTDR = (uint32_t *)UART0_DR;
    
    while(*UARTFR & (1<<5)){
        
    }
    *UARTDR = c;
}
char uart_getc(){
    volatile uint32_t *UARTFR = (uint32_t *)UART0_FR;
    volatile uint32_t *UARTDR = (uint32_t *)UART0_DR;
    
    while(*UARTFR & (1<<4)){
            
    }
    return *UARTDR & 0xFF;
}
void uart_puts(const char *str){
    while (*str){
        uart_putc(*str++);
    }
}

int my_strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    while (*s1 && (*s1 == *s2)) {
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    return (unsigned char)*s1 - (unsigned char)*s2;
}

// Custom implementation of strncmp
int my_strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n) {
    while (n > 0) {
        if (*s1 != *s2) {
            return (unsigned char)*s1 - (unsigned char)*s2;
        }
        if (*s1 == '\0') {
            return 0; // Both strings ended equally
        }
        s1++;
        s2++;
        n--;
    }
    return 0; // First n characters are equal
}

// Function to print the received command in ASCII values for debugging
void print_command(const char *cmd) {
    uart_puts("Received command: ");
    while (*cmd) {
        uart_putc(*cmd);
        cmd++;
    }
    uart_putc('\n');
}

// Command processing function
void process_command(const char *cmd) {
    if (my_strcmp(cmd, "help") == 0) {
        uart_puts("Available commands: help, echo <message>, exit\n");
    } else if (my_strncmp(cmd, "echo ", 5) == 0) {
        uart_puts(cmd + 5); // Print everything after "echo "
        uart_putc('\n');
    } else {
        uart_puts("Unknown command.\n");
    }
}

// Main function
void notmain(void) {
    char c;
    char command[100];
    int index = 0;

    uart_puts("UART test... \n");
    while (1) {
        c = uart_getc();
        if (c == '\r') {
            command[index] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the command

            // Debug print the received command as ASCII values
            print_command(command);

            process_command(command);
            index = 0; // Reset index for next command
        } else if (c == '\b' || c == 127) {
            if (index > 0) {
                index--;
                uart_puts("\b \b"); // Handle backspace
            }
        } else {
            if (index < sizeof(command) - 1) {
                command[index++] = c; // Store character in command buffer
                uart_putc(c); // Echo character
            }
        }
    }
}

when i launched this code i see this pic, that text wasnt set upped:

How can this code been fixed for normal work with buffer which can launch 'commands'?
So, how i compile projects. I use aarch64-linux-gnu:
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -c -Wall -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -march=armv8-a commands.c -o commands.o
and how i run qemu system:
qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt -cpu cortex-a53 -m 128 -serial mon:stdio -kernel os.bin
By the way i have also linker and .s file:
.global _start
_start:
    ldr x0, =0x20000
    mov sp, x0
    bl notmain
hang:
    b hang

.global PUT32
PUT32:
    str w1,[x0]
    ret
    

and here linker:
MEMORY
{
    ram  : ORIGIN = 0x00010000, LENGTH = 32K
}

SECTIONS
{
   .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
   .bss  : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}


Please specify what compiler you use, show how you compile the program and how you run qemu.

@dimich, added.

Can't reproduce. I compiled and linked your program with startup64.s and linker script taken from here (just changed c_entry to notmain). It prints and executes both commands correctly, as expected.

@dimich i added linker and asm code perheps in this code i have some issues?

@dimich i tryed linker and bootload in link what u give me, nothing happened

It looks like some issue with serial<->stdio mapping in qemu or terminal emulator. Try to add -nographic to qemu. Try to replace -serial mon:stdio with -serial mon:telnet::4444,server=on,wait=on and connect from other terminal window with telnet localhost 4444. Since uart_putc() is working, you can add some additional debug output to see what characters are actually received from UART by printing their codes.

You can also compile the program with -Og -ggdb3, run qemu with -s -S, open ELF in gdb: aarch64-linux-gnu-gdb ./os (note os must be ELF file, not raw binary), connect to qemu: (gdb) target remote localhost:1234 and debug your program.

With your startup file and linker script qemu just hangs after printing UART test... and doesn't accept any input. BTW, my qemu version is 9.1.0.

@dimich, not work can we chat one by one that u send all code what u do? Cuz i rebuild my project nothing happened

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
